# Share class code across multiple C# Libraries that reference each other

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to get my head around sharing common Log class across C# Libraries that reference each other. The problem is that I am confused as to which direction to choose.

Example C# Log class code

```
namespace MyLogger.Log
{
    public class MyLogger
    {
        public void Error(string message)
        {
            var eventArgs = new LogGeneratedEventArgs();
            eventArgs.Message = message;
            eventArgs.Type = LogType.Error;
            LogGenerated?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            var eventArgs = new LogGeneratedEventArgs();
            eventArgs.Message = message;
            eventArgs.Type = LogType.Info;
            LogGenerated?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }

        public event EventHandler<LogGeneratedEventArgs> LogGenerated;
    }

    public class LogGeneratedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public LogType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum LogType
    {
        Error, Info
    }
}
```

Say I got 2 other Libraries

1. Library 1
2. Library 2

Both the libraries need to log information of their internal working and depend on each other. So I have a new project for the above Log management class. But I do not intend to create a new reference dependency just to handle logging.

If I create a standalone C# library for the class then I have to update the NuGet package for that Log class library whenever I create new versions of the other 2.

If I add the code of the Log class as "Add to Link" in Visual Studio I get a namespace conflict error when working with other projects that need both the libraries. Moreover, when working with large projects I get multiple namespace options for the same Log class.

How should I go about sharing the Code across the 2 Libraries without having to add new reference dependency and hitting conflicts? :)

Comment: You want to 1) have a single code base for the logging, 2) have it accessible in your assemblies, 3) not create an (assembly) reference in any of the libraries, and 4) not link the code files into the libraries? I think you are out of options.

Comment: @WicherVisser Ikr :) I am at the moment planning to use C# Preprocessor Directives to compile the MyLogger class with different class names to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is against adding an assembly reference?

Comment: @WicherVisser Just the fact that the other libraries are uploaded as NuGet packages I do not wish to add any additional references.

Comment: The best practice is to make a third library for logging.